# Problema de codificación con <form enctype="multipart/form-data">

Tags: java, html

estoy intentando pasar de un Java a otro los inputs de un form, tanto type="text", como type="file", el problema és que los inputs que són texto, al llegar al otro Java, las letras que llevan acento no las codifica bien entiendo, "Gijón" se convierte en "GijÃ³n".

```
<form action="test.jsp" class="formular form form-horizontal well row" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="idFormUserReg" name="form1" novalidate>
        <div class="row" >
            <p class="span5" >
                <label for="idShortCompanyName">Short Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="shortName"  id="idShortName" maxlength="30" class="input-large" value="<%=aShortCompanyName%>">
            </p>
            <p class="span5" >
                <label for="idNameLogo">Logo</label>
                <input type="file" name="logoFile" id="idNameLogo">
                <input type="hidden" name="nameLogo" value="logo_<%=lIdClient%>.png">
            </p>
        </div>
</form
```

He intentado también poner enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8", las inputs texto funcionan bién, pero el file no llega.
Hay alguna otra forma de hacer que lleguen todos bien? Gracias!

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33977270/5587982) de Stackoverflow en inglés.

Comment: Ya tengo puesto esto en los dos Java y nada : <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"

Comment: En la respuesta hay una sugerencia a hacerlo desde la configuración global, en `web.xml` ¿Intentaste eso?

Comment: Si, lo he probado también, aunque lo dice como recomendación, que en vez de hacerlo a todos los archivos hacerlo globalmente en ese, pero creo que es lo mismo

Comment: Ummm no es lo mismo. Puede que en alguna parte haya otra codificación que te esté fastidiando, si lo pones en la configuración es mejor. No está de más probar.

Comment: No si si lo he probado y funciona igual, no sé que puede estar pasando la verdad

Comment: Pero, ¿qué es lo que llega mal codificado, los inputs de texto, el contenido del archivo ¿?

Comment: Llega mal codificado los input type="text", y entiendo que si al nombre del input type="file" pongo una tilde seguramente también llegaría mal

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código donde recibes los datos de este formulario?

Comment: Bueno los recibo a partir de un request, dentro está el campo "attributes", y por ejemplo uno de ellos és multipart.shortName=GijÃ³n